# Android 9.0: HTTP request throws exception in "Minimize mode"

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

Every HTTP request throws failed to connect to Server **wherever App goes in sleep or minimize mode**. This only **happens in Android Pie(9.0)**.

Please check my code below,

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncReadConfig asyncReadConfig = new AsyncReadConfig();
                asyncReadConfig.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class AsyncReadConfig extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Object> {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            try {
                return callGetURLService(CONFIGURATION_URL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e;
            }
        }
    }

    private Object callGetURLService(String path) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String text;
            StringBuilder configParams = new StringBuilder();
            while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
                configParams.append(text);
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(configParams.toString());
            //Doing my stuff

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In my manifeast.xml,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        .
        .
```

In network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">MY_DOMAIN</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I'm just reading text file from server in sleep mode and I'm getting error,

> java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to server

And as I'm switching my App from minimize mode to active mode, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is in the background you cant make network calls unless you are using a Foreground service to make the network call

Comment: Is this new change for Android Pie? should I use foreground service for each network call?

Comment: *Is this new change for Android Pie* ever heard of documentation? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28